# Address(home, a location on google maps, etc.) data type

Tags: community, formula-field, custom-field, fields, data-types

How can I create an address data type?

On my Salesforce there is Billing address.[image]
When I create a new account I see the billing address field and it show something like this.
[image]
How can I create new fields like this? It fills the info from google maps automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet available as a datatype for custom fields. It was accepted as a feature to be implemented about a year ago. You can see it as in development [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVWAA0).

NB: It is possible to add multiple individual fields and support (via code) the ability to geocode these to a geo location.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an example that I might look at to understand better?